# Grow branches of a fractal tree one at a time

Tags: javascript

I am using Javascript and a canvas to create a fractal tree. Most of the code from this comes from a video tutorial I watched, so I am not too familiar with it. I control some of the aspects that determine the tree's appearance with sliders. Here's the javascript:

```
var angle = 0;
var lengthV = 0;
var multiple = 0;
var branches = 2;
var min = 20;
var sliderA;
var sliderL;
var sliderM;
var sliderm;

function setup() {

    var a = document.createTextNode("Angle");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    sliderA = createSlider(0,TWO_PI, PI/4, 0.001); //slider to two pi, starts at pi/4, increments of 0.01

    var l = document.createTextNode("Length");
    document.body.appendChild(l);
    sliderL = createSlider(0,500);

    var m = document.createTextNode("Multiple");
    document.body.appendChild(m);
    sliderM = createSlider(0,0.8,0.4,0.01);

    var i = document.createTextNode("Minimum");
    document.body.appendChild(i);
    sliderm = createSlider(1,400,10,1);

    createCanvas(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
}

function draw() {
    background(255); //canvas colour
    angle = sliderA.value();
    lengthV = sliderL.value();
    multiple = sliderM.value();
    min = sliderm.value();
    stroke(0); //line colour
    translate(0.5*window.innerWidth, height) //sets new origin point for branch
    branch(lengthV);
}

function branch(len) {
    line(0, 0, 0, - len); //makes line
    translate(0, -len);
    if (len > min) { //ensure the branch is larger than minimum
        if (branches == 2) {
            push(); //save transformation state
            rotate(angle); //rotate for first branch
            branch(len * multiple); //repeat loop
            pop(); //return back to original transformations state
            push(); //save transformation state
            rotate(-angle); //rotate other way for second branch
            branch(len * multiple);
            pop();
        }
        if (branches == 3) {
            push(); //save transformation state
            rotate(angle); //rotate for first branch
            branch(len * multiple); //grow branch
            pop(); //return back to original transformations state
            push(); //save transformation state
            rotate(0);
            branch(len * multiple); //grow middle branch
            pop(); //return back to original transformations state
            push(); //save transformation state
            rotate(-angle); //rotate other way for third branch
            branch(len * multiple);
            pop();
        }
    }
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

I have a recursive loop which, depending on the value of the `branches` variable, creates a set number of branches at an angle that is changed by the slider. However, I was wondering whether there was a method to set a timer so that a layer of branches grew every set period of time, instead of all growing at once. My knowledge of Javascript is slightly limited so I appreciate any response you may give.

Comment: Please click the `<>` button and create a [mcve] - we do not see the createSlider code here

Comment: Create slider is in the setup function. However - whether you can see it or not doesn't make a difference to what I was asking. @mplungjan